# the used select statements have a different number of columns mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an error "the used select statements have a different number of columns mysql"

My query

```
SELECT
* FROM
inventory 
WHERE
barcode1 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
OR barcode2 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
OR barcode3 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
OR barcode4 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' UNION
SELECT
p.id AS 'PartId',
m.`Name` AS 'Model',
c.`Name` AS 'Color',
pt.`Name` AS 'PartType' 
FROM
inventory i
JOIN part p ON p.Id = i.PartId
JOIN model m ON m.Id = p.ModelId
JOIN color c ON c.Id = p.ColorId
JOIN parttype pt ON pt.Id = p.PartTypeId 
WHERE
barcode1 = @barcode
OR barcode2 = @barcode
OR barcode3 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
OR barcode4 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2';
```

What i want to get is all the data in inventory table in the first select statement, and another one is from another table.

Before, I have two queries which is

```
SELECT
    * 
     FROM
    inventory 
    WHERE
    barcode1 = @Barcode 
    OR barcode2 = @Barcode 
    OR barcode3 = @Barcode 
    OR barcode4 = @Barcode`
```

that will retrieve all the information in inventory and the other one is

```
SELECT
p.id AS 'PartId',
m.`Name` AS 'Model',
c.`Name` AS 'Color',
pt.`Name` AS 'PartType'
FROM
inventory i
JOIN part p ON p.Id = i.PartId
JOIN model m ON m.Id = p.ModelId
JOIN color c ON c.Id = p.ColorId
JOIN parttype pt ON pt.Id = p.PartTypeId 
WHERE
barcode1 = @Barcode
OR barcode2 = @Barcode
OR barcode3 = @Barcode
OR barcode4 = @Barcode
```

That will load just the four columns.

Since my output load too slow, i will combine it in one query. Is this possible? How can I do that?

I'm a beginner in MySQL.

Comment: You have edited the question, however I still don't have full understanding,  can you please add simplified sample data that is returned from first query, then from second, and finally the result that you wish to achieve, like in my answer where I show tableA and tableB

Comment: I already know what to do. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you are using a union (ie a vertical merge) when a join(a horizontal merge) would seem more appropriate

```
SELECT i.*,   
p.id AS 'PartId',
m.`Name` AS 'Model',
c.`Name` AS 'Color',
pt.`Name` AS 'PartType'
FROM
inventory i
JOIN part p ON p.Id = i.PartId
JOIN model m ON m.Id = p.ModelId
JOIN color c ON c.Id = p.ColorId
JOIN parttype pt ON pt.Id = p.PartTypeId 
WHERE
barcode1 = @Barcode
OR barcode2 = @Barcode
OR barcode3 = @Barcode
OR barcode4 = @Barcode
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is because you use `Union` on two tables with different number of column. For Example if you get something in TableA:

```
| Id | Name | Age|
+----+------+----+
| 1  | Andy | 3  |
```

And another TableB

```
| Id | Name | Age| Gender |
+----+------+----+--------|
| 1  | Andy | 3  | Male   |
```

If you try to union them you will get error, as they cannot be combined (because of different number of columns).

So your problem is that your first `Select *...` return more columns than the second select where you select only 4 columns. The key to solve it, is to specify exact which columns you need to select so that both selects have same number of columns.

Something like this

```
SELECT
    p.id AS 'PartId',
    m.`Name` AS 'Model',
    c.`Name` AS 'Color',
    pt.`Name` AS 'PartType' 
FROM
    inventory i
    JOIN part p ON p.Id = i.PartId
    JOIN model m ON m.Id = p.ModelId
    JOIN color c ON c.Id = p.ColorId
    JOIN parttype pt ON pt.Id = p.PartTypeId 
WHERE
    i.barcode1 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
    OR i.barcode2 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
    OR i.barcode3 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
    OR i.barcode4 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
UNION
SELECT
    p.id AS 'PartId',
    m.`Name` AS 'Model',
    c.`Name` AS 'Color',
    pt.`Name` AS 'PartType' 
FROM
    inventory i
    JOIN part p ON p.Id = i.PartId
    JOIN model m ON m.Id = p.ModelId
    JOIN color c ON c.Id = p.ColorId
    JOIN parttype pt ON pt.Id = p.PartTypeId 
WHERE
    barcode1 = @barcode
    OR barcode2 = @barcode
    OR barcode3 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2' 
    OR barcode4 = 'DR963560860GYYQBKBBD2';
```

Comment: But how can I select all the data in inventory and another data in the second selection with specific data to get?

Comment: Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Specifically, I have 2 queries already, first is SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE barcode = @barcode1 OR barcode2 = @barcode2 OR barcode3 = @barcode3, barcode4 = @barcode4. The other one is SELECT
    p.id AS 'PartId',
    m.`Name` AS 'Model',
    c.`Name` AS 'Color',
    pt.`Name` AS 'PartType' 
FROM
    inventory i
    JOIN part p ON p.Id = i.PartId
    JOIN model m ON m.Id = p.ModelId
    JOIN color c ON c.Id = p.ColorId
    JOIN parttype pt ON pt.Id = p.PartTypeId 
WHERE
    barcode1 = @barcode
    OR barcode2 = @barcode
    OR barcode3 = @barcode 
    OR barcode4 = @barcode;

Comment: @CloudCaineLarazza can you please edit your question instead of adding it in comments, and if you can please try to provide simplified sample data (like what you have, and what is expected result)

Comment: Since my output load too slow, I will combine the 2 queries if possible, but i don't have any idea how to do it..

Comment: @CloudCaineLarazza what data returns on first select? and what kind of data is returned on second select? if they  have different columns then how do you plan on combining them? It is a bit difficult to understand exactly, so please try to provide some sample data in your question

Comment: Edited question